# Error inserting data into mysql

Tags: csv, mysql

I am trying to insert data from a csv file into mysql using BigDump.

It stops on line 2, with the error:

> "Query: INSERT INTO location VALUES
>   (1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,, );
>
> MySQL: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' )' at line 1"

If I run the statement from withing phpmyadmin, it says:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' )' at line 1"

What can I do to make the data get into the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commas with no values looks sketchy to me.

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,, );
```

should probably be

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,NULL,
```

NULL);

Answer (score 2):

Does your insert statement contain values for every column in the table?  If not, you have to name the columns.

For example,

```
insert into location (col1, col2, col3) values (1, 2, 3);
```

If you show us the structure of the LOCATION table you can get better answers.

Comment: Thank you, I prefered to change the data instead of the code of the script.